# Java: Menu taking input and then exiting the program

Tags: java, methods, menu

So, the issue is that my program goes fine through the process of collecting the two integers to go into the rational class, but then upon getting to the menu, it just exits after taking the choice.  I've no idea why and no one is around to help.

EDIT: After significant fiddling, I've managed to at least get the system to give me some output: that is, that regardless of the number that I put in it is giving me the invalid output.  I'm thinking maybe I should go back to the switch/case?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RationalDriver
{
  private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  private static char choice;
  private static String input;



  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    printHeading();
    Rational first = new Rational();
    numberOne(first);
    Rational second = new Rational();
    numberTwo(second);
    menu(first, second);
  }

  public static void menu(Rational first, Rational second)
  {
    try{
    displayMenu();
    getValue(choice);

    if(choice == '1')
    {
      System.out.println("\n" + first + " + " + second + " equals ");
      first.add(second);
      System.out.println(first);
    }

    else if(choice == '2')
    {
      System.out.println("\n" + first + " - " + second + " equals ");
      first.subtract(second);
      System.out.println(first);
    }

    else if(choice == '3')
    {
      System.out.println("\n" + first + " * " + second + " equals ");
      first.multiply(second);
      System.out.println(first);
    }

    else if(choice == '4')
    {
      System.out.println("\n" + first + " / " + second + " equals ");
      first.divide(second);
      System.out.println(first);
    }

    else if(choice == '5')
    {
      System.out.println("\nAre " + first + " and " + second + " equal?");
      if(first.equals(second))
      {
        System.out.println("\nYes!");
      }
    }

    else if(choice == '6')
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter a new rational number: ");
      numberOne(first);
    }

    else if(choice == '7')
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter a new rational number: ");
      numberTwo(second);
    }

    else if(choice == '8')
    {
      System.out.println("You chose to exit.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("You did not choose a valid entry.");
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  private static void printHeading()  // printHeading method
  {
    System.out.println("Oliver, James");
    System.out.println("CSC201-02PR");
    System.out.println("Dr. Java");
    System.out.println("Project 7");
    System.out.println("Rational Number");
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void displayMenu()
  {
    System.out.println("Enter the corresponding number for the desired action:");
    System.out.println("1. Addition");
    System.out.println("2. Subtraction");
    System.out.println("3. Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4. Division");
    System.out.println("5. Test for Equality");
    System.out.println("6. Change 1st Rational Number");
    System.out.println("7. Change 2nd Rational Number");
    System.out.println("8. Exit");
  }

  public static char getValue(char choice)
  {
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your menu option (1 - 8):");
    choice = in.next().charAt(0);
    return choice;
  }

  public static void numberOne(Rational first)
  {
    int numer = 0;
    int denom = 1;
    boolean breaker = false;
    while(!breaker)
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter your first numerator:");
      input = in.next();
      numer = Integer.parseInt(input);
      System.out.println("Please enter your first denominator:");
      input = in.next();
      denom = Integer.parseInt(input);
      if(denom == 0)
      {
        System.out.println("Denominator cannot be undefined.");
        denom = in.nextInt();
      }
      else
        breaker = true;
    }

    first.setNumer(numer);
    first.setDenom(denom);
    first.normalize();
    System.out.println("Your rational number is: " + first + "\n");
  }

  public static void numberTwo(Rational second)
  {
    int numer = 0;
    int denom = 1;
    boolean breaker = false;
    while(!breaker)
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter your second numerator:");
      input = in.next();
      numer = Integer.parseInt(input);
      System.out.println("Please enter your second denominator:");
      input = in.next();
      denom = Integer.parseInt(input);
      if(denom == 0)
      {
        System.out.println("Denominator cannot be undefined.");
        denom = in.nextInt();
      }
      else
        breaker = true;
    }

    second.setNumer(numer);
    second.setDenom(denom);
    second.normalize();
    System.out.println("\nYour rational number is: " + second + "\n");
  }

}
```

Here's the Rational class that I've made:

```
public class Rational
{

  private int numerator;     // instance variable for the numerator
  private int denominator;   // instance variable for the denominator

  public Rational()          // Constructor
  {
    numerator = 0;
    denominator = 1;
  }

  public Rational(int numer, int denom) // Overloaded Constructor
  {
    numerator = numer;
    denominator = denom;
    normalize();
  }

  public void setNumer(int numer) // Setter for the Numerator value
  {
    numerator = numer;
  }

  public void setDenom(int denom) // Setter for the Denominator value
  {
    denominator = denom;
  }

  public void normalize()
  {
    if(denominator < 0)
    {
      denominator = -denominator;
      numerator = -numerator;
    }
  }

  public int getNumer()    // Numerator Getter
  {
    return numerator;
  }

  public int getDenom()    // Denominator Getter
  {
    return denominator;
  }

  public void add(Rational second)      // Addition method
  {
    int a = this.getNumer();
    int b = this.getDenom();
    int c = second.getNumer();
    int d = second.getDenom();
    numerator = ((a * d) + (b * c));
    denominator = (b * d);
    this.normalize();
  }

  public void subtract(Rational second) // Subtraction Method
  {
    int a = this.getNumer();
    int b = this.getDenom();
    int c = second.getNumer();
    int d = second.getDenom();
    numerator = ((a * d) - (b * c));
    denominator = (b * d);
    this.normalize();    
  }

  public void multiply(Rational second) // Multiplication Method
  {
    int a = this.getNumer();
    int b = this.getDenom();
    int c = second.getNumer();
    int d = second.getDenom();
    numerator = (a * c);
    denominator = (b * d);
    this.normalize();    
  }

  public void divide(Rational second)  // Division Method
  {
    int a = this.getNumer();
    int b = this.getDenom();
    int c = second.getNumer();
    int d = second.getDenom();
    numerator = (a * d);
    denominator = (b * c);
    this.normalize();
  }

  public boolean equals(Object second) // Equals method
  {
    if(second == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
    if(!(second instanceof Rational))
    {
      return false;
    }
    Rational other = (Rational)second;
    return this.getNumer() * other.getDenom() == other.getNumer() * this.getDenom();
  }

  public String toString()  // toString method
  {
    if(numerator == 0)
    {
      return "Result = 0";
    }
    if(denominator == 1)
    {
      return Integer.toString(numerator);
    }
    return Integer.toString(numerator) + "/" + Integer.toString(denominator);
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe menu shpuld be called in a loop? As it now is, its called once and main terminates.

Comment: You could return boolean and get rid of System.exit a well.

Comment: And you never read value of getChoice() in menu

Comment: I've put the entire code in there now.